# <br /> and highlight_string

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting

I want to display code on the browser instead of executing it, so I use `highlight_string`,

```
<?php highlight_string('function foo(items) {
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        alert(items[i] + "juhu");
    }   // Real Tab.
}')?>
```

returns,

```
<code><span style="color: #000000"> function&nbsp;foo(items)&nbsp;{ <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for&nbsp;(var&nbsp;i=0;&nbsp;i&lt;items.length;&nbsp;i++)&nbsp;{ <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;alert(items[i]&nbsp;+&nbsp;"juhu"); <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;//&nbsp;Real&nbsp;Tab. <br />}</span> </code>

<code>
```

But I am after **new lines** without `<br/>`s,

```
<code><span style="color: #000000">

function&nbsp;foo(items)&nbsp;{
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for&nbsp;(var&nbsp;i=0;&nbsp;i&lt;items.length;&nbsp;i++)&nbsp;{

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;alert(items[i]&nbsp;+&nbsp;"juhu");

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;//&nbsp;Real&nbsp;Tab.

}</span>

</code>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace every `<br />` tag with normal linebreaks (\r\n) and output your string, like this:

```
$data = highlight_string('function foo(items) {
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    alert(items[i] + "juhu");
}   // Real Tab.
}',true);
 $data = str_replace('<br />',"\r\n",$data);
 echo '<pre>';
 echo $data;
 echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try making a custom function.Get the string as parameter,explode the string by  'return',use highlight_string function on sub strings in a loop and then concatenate all of the sub strings to form the desired string.